# How to write destructor to be able to compile the code and free all allocated memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor

I've created custom class, that shall behave like a matrix. I've got there some basic operations and everything seems to be working well... Nevertheless, I can't find out, what shall I write to destructor of this class to free all allocated memory. Would you please advice me?

```
class CMatrix {
public:

class Proxy {
    friend class CMatrix;

    const CMatrix* cmat;
    CMatrix *matrix;
    size_t n;

    Proxy(const CMatrix& m, size_t i)
    : cmat(&m), matrix(), n(i) {
    }

    Proxy(CMatrix& m, size_t i)
    : cmat(&m), matrix(&m), n(i) {
    }

    public:

    const double& operator[](size_t j) const {
       return cmat->_arrayofarrays[n * cmat->y + j];
    }

    double& operator[](size_t j) {
        if (matrix) {
            return matrix->_arrayofarrays[n * cmat->y + j];
        } else return cmat->_arrayofarrays[cmat->y];
    }
    };

    const Proxy operator[](size_t i) const {
        return Proxy(*this, i);
    }

    Proxy operator[](size_t i) {
        return Proxy(*this, i);
    }

    CMatrix() {
    _arrayofarrays = NULL;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
};

// constructor

CMatrix(size_t x, size_t y) : _arrayofarrays(), x(x), y(y) {
    _arrayofarrays = new double[ x * y ]();
}

// destructor

~CMatrix() {
    // ?!?!???!?!?!?!!!!?!?!? 
    // #$#%@^$!!!!@$#%!!
}

// copy constructor

CMatrix(const CMatrix& other) : _arrayofarrays(), x(other.x), y(other.y) {
    delete [] _arrayofarrays;
    _arrayofarrays = new double[x * y];
    if (_arrayofarrays)
        std::copy(other._arrayofarrays, other._arrayofarrays + (x * y), _arrayofarrays);
}

CMatrix& operator =(const CMatrix& rval) {
    delete [] _arrayofarrays;
    _arrayofarrays = new double[ rval.x * rval.y];
    std::copy(rval._arrayofarrays, rval._arrayofarrays + (rval.x * rval.y), _arrayofarrays);
    x = rval.x;
    y = rval.y;
    return *this;
}



double *_arrayofarrays;
size_t x;
size_t y;
};
```

EDIT:

actually now I've realized, that it crashes after running this part of code. Before calling this code, I have there a instances of my class, let's call it `a,b,c` and then I want to set `a = b-c`;
this works well for the first time...but when I want to repeat it, then it crashes

```
CMatrix CMatrix::operator-(const CMatrix &matrix) const {
if (this->x != matrix.x || this->y != matrix.y) {
    throw CSizeException(matrix.y, matrix.x, this->y, this->x, '+');
};
CMatrix m(this->x, this->y);
CMatrix l(matrix.x, matrix.y);
l._arrayofarrays = this->_arrayofarrays;
CMatrix o(matrix.y, matrix.y);
o = matrix;


CMatrix result(this->x, this->y);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->x; i++)
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < this->y; j++)
        m[i][j] = l[i][j] - o[i][j];           
return m;
}
```

Comment: You've already worked out how to delete the memory in other member functions, why can't you work out how to do it in the destructor?

Comment: I don't know, how to do it in this case, because calling delete[] _arrayofarrays causes segfault in this case... it is actually some sort of 2D array thanks to that Proxy class

Comment: use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays and `new`. let it handle the memory management for you.

Comment: If you not sure you working with memory well, try to use some memory analysis tool like valgrind

Comment: Heh... wonder where this came from.

Comment: @Dworza In what way is it a 2D array? It's a 1D array, allocated by `new double[x * y]`.

Comment: @Dworza, if `delete[] _arrayofarrays` doesn't work in the destructor then it's wrong in the other member functions too. Or if it's right there then it's right in the destructor too, and your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
~CMatrix() {
    delete[] _arrayofarrays;
}
```

All arrays allocated with `new[]` must be destroyed by a matching call to `delete[]`. Moreover, you can remove the `delete[]` statement from the copy constructor:

```
CMatrix(const CMatrix& other) : _arrayofarrays(), x(other.x), y(other.y) {
    // delete [] _arrayofarrays;
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // This is unnecessary: you are creating a new object, so this data member
    // is not pointing to any previously allocated array

    // ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> (*from the comments*) I can't use this code... `_arrayofarrays` is actually 2D array, so this causes that running of the program fails..probably segfault

This is incorrect: `_arrayofarrays` is a 1D array, and calling `delete[]` is the proper way do destroy it. If doing so leads to a segfault, probably you're doing something wrong in the rest of your code.

As an advice, it is usually a good idea to **avoid manual memory management** through raw pointers, `new`, and `delete` (or their array counterparts), because it is error-prone and easily leads to memory leaks or dereferencing of invalid pointers/reference.

Consider using standard containers such as `std::vector<>` or `std::deque<>` instead.

---

**EDIT:**

In the code of `operator -` you are doing:

```
l._arrayofarrays = this->_arrayofarrays;
```

This way you are having *two* matrix objects which encapsulate the same array: therefore, deleting one of the two will make the other one invalid as well. This is probably the root cause of your problem.

Also, you are creating way too many temporaries in there. Unless I'm missing something, this should be enough:

```
CMatrix CMatrix::operator-(const CMatrix &matrix) const {
    if (this->x != matrix.x || this->y != matrix.y) {
        throw CSizeException(matrix.y, matrix.x, this->y, this->x, '+');
    };

    CMatrix result(this->x, this->y);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->x; i++)
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < this->y; j++)
            result[i][j] = (*this)[i][j] - matrix[i][j];

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @JonathanWakely: The class has a default constructor that sets `_arrayofarrays` to `NULL`

Comment: I can't use this code... _arrayofarrays is actually 2D array, so this causes that running of the program fails..probably segfault

Comment: @AndyProwl I wouldn't expect *you* to check for NULL when deleting pointers. :)

Comment: @AndyProwl, So what?  `delete[]` checks for null anyway

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Right, forgot. Sorry

Comment: It is not a 2D array because you allocated it as `double[x * y]`. 2D array would be `double** arrayofarrays = new double*[x]` and then for every `i` do `arrayofarrays[i] = new double[y]`. In your case, it is a plain 1D array.

Comment: @riv That's not a 2D array either.

Comment: It is as close as you can get to a (dynamic) 2D array in C, and you access the elements as `arrayofarrays[i][j]`. Sure, there are static arrays declared as `double array[x][y]`, but you can't create those dynamically. By the way, the crash was probably caused by the copy constructor as it was deleting a garbage pointer.

Comment: If it were a 2D dynamic array, you would need to delete it the same way you allocated it. `for(i ...) delete[] arrayofarrays[i];`, then `delete[] arrayofarrays`

Comment: Yes, now I see... Nevertheless calling delete[] _arrayofarrays in destructor causes crash... Pls check the update of my post for new info.

Comment: +1 for the update on `operator -()`, but you left out the memory leak resulting from the assignment to `l._arrayofarrays` =P. Also, the OP would be *far* better served to write an `operator -=()`, then after properly size-checking, have `operator -()` simply `CMatrix m = *this; m -= other; return m;`

Comment: @AndyProwl Indeed. Likewise, because the dimensions are validated the two-dimensional enumerator isn't needed either. Just walk both simple dim arrays and stuff the difference in the target array for each element. the result is the same as a 2D row-by-row, col-by-col subtraction.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Correct again :)

Answer (score 2):

The way to delete the memory in the destructor is the same as you wrote it in the other member functions:

```
    delete [] _arrayofarrays;
```

If this crashes then you must be corrupting memory somewhere else. Try using `valgrind` to check for memory errors.

There are some problems with your copy constructor:

```
CMatrix(const CMatrix& other) : _arrayofarrays(), x(other.x), y(other.y) {
    delete [] _arrayofarrays;
```

This is useless, there's nothing to delete yet.

```
    _arrayofarrays = new double[x * y];
    if (_arrayofarrays)
```

This `if` is useless, `new` will either throw an exception or return a non-null pointer, so checking if it's null is useless.

```
        std::copy(other._arrayofarrays, other._arrayofarrays + (x * y), _arrayofarrays);
}
```

There are some problems with your assignment operator too:

```
CMatrix& operator =(const CMatrix& rval) {
    delete [] _arrayofarrays;
    _arrayofarrays = new double[ rval.x * rval.y];
```

If the `new` allocation throws an exception then you leave `_arrayofarrays` holding a dangling pointer, you should either allocate the new memory *before* deleting the old memory or zero the old pointer after using `delete[]`